# copy data from a worksheet till a condition

Tags: vba, excel

I have a worksheet which contains data in column B to column D. I want to copy the data from B4 to till the cell value which has space infront of it and paste it in a separate sheet and change the sheet as the value B4 and then it has to copy the next cell values untill the cell value with space infront and it continues till column B has empty cells.

In addition to that i have to enter serial no in column A respect to the data without space inits intial stage. i have attached the input and expected output image for your reference.

input:
[image]

expected output:

[image]

please help on this issue.

Comment: Please rewrite your question, it's not written clearly.

Comment: i want to insert serial numbers in Column A if the cell value in column B is starting with out space. For more clarity please refer the image that i have attached. @ Josh Friedlander

Comment: Can't you sort your data alphabetically, and then add the numbers to those without spaces?

Comment: Actually the above data are extracted from web and it is populated here.@JoshFriedlander

Comment: sorting doesn't play any role in this@JoshFriedlander

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your sheet is as follows:

[image]

Enter the following formula in the `Cell A4`

```
=IF(LEFT(B4,1)<>" ",COUNTA($A$2:A3)+1-COUNTBLANK($A$2:A3),"")
```

Drag/Copy down formula as required.

If you are looking for a VBA solution, following should work:

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, index As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    index = 1
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")   '---->change the sheet name as required
    lastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng = ws.Range("B4:B" & lastRow)
    For i = 4 To lastRow
        If Left(ws.Cells(i, 2).Value, 1) <> " " Then
            ws.Cells(i, 1).Value = index
            index = index + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**_______________________________________________________________________________**

***EDIT 1*** : First copy data from `Sheet1` to `Sheet2` and then add serial numbers.

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, index As Long, i As Long
    Dim rng As Range

    index = 1
    Set ws1 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")   '---->change the sheet name as required
    Set ws2 = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")
    lastRow = ws1.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ws1.Range("B2:D" & lastRow).Copy Destination:=ws2.Range("B2")
    Set rng = ws2.Range("B4:B" & lastRow)
    For i = 4 To lastRow
        If Left(ws2.Cells(i, 2).Value, 1) <> " " Then
            ws2.Cells(i, 1).Value = index
            index = index + 1
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

**_______________________________________________________________________________**

***EDIT 2*** :

```
Sub Demo()
    Dim srcWS As Worksheet, destWS As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long, index As Long, i As Long
    Dim copyRng As Range, rng1 As Range, rng2 As Range

    index = 1
    Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")   '---->change the sheet name as required
    lastRow = srcWS.Cells(Rows.count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    Set rng1 = srcWS.Cells(4, 2)
    For i = 4 To lastRow
        If Left(srcWS.Cells(i, 2).Value, 1) <> " " Then
            srcWS.Cells(i, 1).Value = index
            index = index + 1
            If i <> 4 Then
                Set rng2 = srcWS.Cells(i - 1, 4)
                Set destWS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
                srcWS.Range(rng1, rng2).Copy Destination:=destWS.Range("B4")
                Set rng1 = srcWS.Cells(i, 2)
            End If
        End If
    Next i
    Set rng2 = srcWS.Cells(lastRow, 4)

    Set destWS = Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.count))
    srcWS.Range(rng1, rng2).Copy Destination:=destWS.Range("B4")

End Sub
```

Comment: thanks It works as i expected, can we copy the data till before serial number and paste it in separate sheet.@Mrig

Comment: @DINESHKUMARPALANISAMY - Yeah it can be.

Comment: thanks for your effort. But i need to copy content till before serial no 2 and paste it in new sheet@Mrig

Comment: @DINESHKUMARPALANISAMY - Edited code will copy data from 'Cell B2' to 'Cell D till last row' from 'Sheet1' and will paste to 'Cell B2' in 'Sheet2'.

Comment: i dont want to copy till last row, i wamt to copy till D12 for this example as A13 is "2". (this may vary according to the data that i fetch)@Mrig

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142073/discussion-between-dineshkumar-palanisamy-and-mrig).

Comment: It doesn't works. the data from whole Serial number 1 has to be copied and pasted, it is copying only serial number 1 alone

Comment: @DINESHKUMARPALANISAMY - `Set srcWS = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1")` have you changed the sheet name here?

Comment: @DINESHKUMARPALANISAMY - Any success?